# Windows 8.1 cannot be started from grub2

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, grub, bootloader, mbr

today I decided to use linux again after installing Windows 8.1...
I've tried to boot one of the already existing Linux partitions on my computer but I wasn't successful.

So I installed PinguyOS (A Ubuntu based distro) and booted it without any problems. When I finished everything I needed to do in Linux I wanted to go back to Windows. Anyway, here's the problem:

Whenever I try to select the option "Windows 8 (loader)" in grub2, it just goes back to grub. I suppose this is because of grub2 being installed on the same partition as the windows 8 loader.

I've already tried the following: https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/

Anyway, no OS was found afterwards... So I installed Linux with grub2 again and ran into the same problem.

I'm able to boot BOOTMGR directly using [this](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) tool tho...

**EDIT:**
I have Legacy boot mode enabled in my BIOS.

---

If I could, I would just reinstall windows8 but the problem is that I have gotten my license over Dreamspark and therefor cannot activate it a second time.

Thanks in advance and merry christmas!

Answer (score 0):

From what you said i think that you used the entire disk to install Linux. That may be reason Grub fails when it try to load windows because windows may have been removed in the process.

If you have installed Linux and windows in two separate partitions properly then

- If you want to get back access to your windows then here is [something](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/) you should try. It describe how to reinstall the windows boot-loader.
- Or you can try to reinstall grub boot loader as described in this [tutorial](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) after booting to your Linux(you said you can boot to linux with no problem).

Answer (score 0):

As I was still able to boot Windows using Hiren's Boot CD, I could reinstall the bootloader using a tool called EasyBCD.